# How can I rotate a string?

Tags: python

How can I rotate a string by two places, e.g. rotate `'MyString'` to `'ngMyStri'`?

heres my code, I keep getting `'nMyStri'`

```
string = 'MyString'

input("enter the word string: ")
string = string[-2] + string[:-2]
print(string)
```

Comment: use `string[-2:] + string[:-2]`

Answer (score 3):

`[-2]` gives you the character at the 2nd last position. You want that character onwards to the end of the string:

```
string = string[-2:] + string[:-2] 
print(string)
```

Output:

```
ngMyStri
```

Comment: Wait...I found it!

Answer (score 2):

change line 4 in your code to :

```
string = string[-2:] + string[:-2]
```

Explanation : string[-2] returns the second last element of your string, but using '**:**' will give you the slice from second last element to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate a string you can convert it to `deque` and use the method `rotate()`. After rotating you can join letters to one string using `''.join()`:

```
from collections import deque

s = 'ABCDE'

d = deque(s)
print(d)

d.rotate(2)
print(''.join(d))
```

Output:

```
deque(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
DEABC
```